# Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, controller

Im getting above error when i made a post request from POSTMAN.Everything works fine but only post request getting me error:((

**The below is the handler which gets called when post request is made:**

```
exports.createTour = async (req, res) => {
  try {
   
    const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);

    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        tour: newTour
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: err
    });
  }
};
```

**tourRoutes.js**

This is my routes file........

```
const express = require('express');
const tourController = require('./../controllers/tourController');

const router = express.Router();


router
  .route('/')
  .get(tourController.getAllTours)
  .post(tourController.createTour);

router
  .route('/:id')
  .get(tourController.getTour)
  .patch(tourController.updateTour)
  .delete(tourController.deleteTour);

module.exports = router;
```

**Server.js**
This is my server file all server related info is here....

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });
const app = require('./app');

const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  '<password>',
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log('DB connection successful!'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Comment: can you edit to include the source of `Tour.create`? and the payload you are sending with Postman? From the error message, I'm guessing the post from postman has invalid JSON

Comment: This is my JSON:   {
    'name':'Test tour 50',
    'price':456,
    'rating':4.5
}

Comment: Thanks Man I got it....Its the error in JSON in my POSTMAN nly. I changed it and started working. I changed it to       {
    "name":"Tour traveller 50",
    "price":555,
    "rating": 4.5
}

Comment: That's invalid. JSON only allows double quotes